# Name for 3 full diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I was wondering if there is a name or a terminology for a matrix with 3 full diagonals. It is similar with tridiagonal matrices, where the later is only centered at diagonal.

For such a matrix,
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 &  &  & c_n\\c_1 & a_2 & b_2 & & \\ & c_2 & a_3 & b_3 \\
 & & \cdots & \cdots & \\ b_n & & & c_{n-1} & a_n \end{bmatrix}$$

is there any reference/algorithms on finding its eigenvalue when $n$ is large and with/without symmetric assumption?

Comment: @jgd1729 thanks for your reply. From wiki, it seems each column of circulant matrix is a permutation of a vector while in my case, column vectors may vary. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is sometimes called a ["band" or "banded" matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix). I am not aware of any literature about this specific distribution of entries.

Comment: One approach that might be helpful is to begin with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) that you get by setting $b_n$ and $c_n$ to zero, then adjusting that result with a low-rank update to the eigenvalues and eigenvectors corresponding to a restoration of those entries ([some possible leads for that here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/448703/34894)).